# CodeIgniter: Anchor or a href?

Tags: codeigniter

Whats difference in using `anchor` in CodeIgniter instead of using traditional html `a href` tag?
Should I use anchor in Views or HTML a href? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I honestly feel like there is minimal difference. I personally use html anchor because it uses more html.

If you want to add context path inside a view, just do this:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('path/name');?>">anchor</a>
```

However, one of the advantages of using codeigniter anchor is that, if you want to build contents dynamically:

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $anchors[] = anchor('path/name', 'anchor');
}
```

is easier than

```
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
   $anchors[] = '<a href="'.site_url('path/name').'">anchor</a>';
}
```

Do you see the difference? :)

Answer (score 2):

`anchor` in CodeIgniter can do things like prefix the context path, so you just need to provide the URL of your controller (e.g. '/login') rather than the whole path to your application.

When you use A HREF, you have to ensure your paths are always relative or include the entire path to your app (i.e. /someapp/login).